# how to replace selected text to sentence case in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, case, sentencecase

i am in search of this as I see that Microsoft Word having this feature.
Sentence Case and Toggle Case.

I wan to add this two items in the Menu item so that the selected text will convert to the Sentence Case if i click ' Convert to sentence Case' or toggle case if i click 'conv. to toggle case'...

I am known with the upper case, lower case, and proper case and the code are as follow but what for the sentence case and toggle case.?

```
Private Sub LowerCaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LowerCaseToolStripMenuItem.Click
    TextBox1.SelectedText = TextBox1.SelectedText.ToLower
End Sub
Private Sub UpperCaseToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpperCaseToolStripMenuItem.Click
    TextBox1.SelectedText = TextBox1.SelectedText.ToUpper
End Sub
Private Sub TitleCaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TitleCaseToolStripMenuItem.Click
    TextBox1.SelectedText = StrConv(TextBox1.SelectedText, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
End Sub
```

But yes, put the code only for VB.Net not for C# or else.
I am just going for vb.net, I get two to 3 article on C# but none for vb.net so please...

you can also place the project link to help me out
Thank you

Comment: @ deep the `TitleCaseToolStripMenuItem_Click` does the sentence case action

Comment: But what there will be the code?
I mean: Sentence Case: (Sentence case)
Title case is Word case (Word Case)
Toglle case (tOGGLE cASE)
Reply me fast

Answer (score 0):

I wrote time ago a method to do what you need.

Usage:

· For Sentence Case (TitleCase)

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = 
StringRenamer.Rename(TextBox1.SelectedText, StringRenamer.StringCase.Title)
```

· For ToggleCase

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = 
StringRenamer.Rename(TextBox1.SelectedText, StringRenamer.StringCase.Toggle)
```

· For ProperCase (WordCase)

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = 
StringRenamer.Rename(TextBox1.SelectedText, StringRenamer.StringCase.Word)
```

· For LowerCase

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = 
StringRenamer.Rename(TextBox1.SelectedText, StringRenamer.StringCase.Lower)
```

· For UpperCase

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = 
StringRenamer.Rename(TextBox1.SelectedText, StringRenamer.StringCase.Upper)
```

---

```
#Region " String Renamer "

' [ String Renamer ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
' Examples :
'
' MsgBox(StringRenamer.Rename("Hello World!", StringRenamer.StringCase.Upper))
' MsgBox(StringRenamer.Rename("Hello World!", StringRenamer.StringCase.Upper, New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\s+"), "-", RegexOptions.None))

Public Class StringRenamer

    Private Shared output As String = String.Empty

    Public Enum StringCase As Short

        ''' <summary>
        ''' LowerCase
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ABCDEF
        ''' Output: abcdef
        ''' </summary>
        Lower = 0

        ''' <summary>
        ''' UpperCase.
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : abcdef
        ''' Output: ABCDEF
        ''' </summary>
        Upper = 1

        ''' <summary>
        ''' TitleCase.
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : abcdef
        ''' Output: Abcdef
        ''' </summary>
        Title = 2

        ''' <summary>
        ''' WordCase.
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : abc def
        ''' Output: Abc Def
        ''' </summary>
        Word = 3

        ''' <summary>
        ''' CamelCase (With first letter to LowerCase).
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ABC DEF
        ''' Output: abcDef
        ''' </summary>
        Camel_Lower = 4

        ''' <summary>
        ''' CamelCase (With first letter to UpperCase).
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ABC DEF
        ''' Output: AbcDef
        ''' </summary>
        Camel_Upper = 5

        ''' <summary>
        ''' MixedCase (With first letter to LowerCase).
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ab cd ef
        ''' Output: aB Cd eF
        ''' </summary>
        Mixed_TitleLower = 6

        ''' <summary>
        ''' MixedCase (With first letter to UpperCase).
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ab cd ef
        ''' Output: Ab cD Ef
        ''' </summary>
        Mixed_TitleUpper = 7

        ''' <summary>
        ''' MixedCase (With first letter of each word to LowerCase).
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ab cd ef
        ''' Output: aB cD eF
        ''' </summary>
        Mixed_Word_Lower = 8

        ''' <summary>
        ''' MixedCase (With first letter of each word to UpperCase).
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : ab cd ef
        ''' Output: Ab Cd Ef
        ''' </summary>
        Mixed_Word_Upper = 9

        ''' <summary>
        ''' ToggleCase.
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : abc def ghi
        ''' Output: aBC dEF gHI
        ''' </summary>
        Toggle = 10

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Inverts the characters.
        ''' 
        ''' [Example]
        ''' Input : Hello World!
        ''' Output: hELLO wORLD!
        ''' </summary>
        Inverted = 11

    End Enum

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Rename a string to the specified StringCase.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function Rename(ByVal Text As String,
                                  ByVal sCase As StringCase) As String

        Select Case sCase

            Case StringCase.Lower

                Return Text.ToLower

            Case StringCase.Upper

                Return Text.ToUpper

            Case StringCase.Title

                Return Char.ToUpper(Text.First) & Text.Substring(1).ToLower

            Case StringCase.Word

                Return Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text.ToLower)

            Case StringCase.Camel_Lower

                Return Char.ToLower(Text.First) &
                       Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text.ToLower).
                       Replace(" ", "").
                       Substring(1)

            Case StringCase.Camel_Upper

                Return Char.ToUpper(Text.First) &
                       Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text.ToLower).
                       Replace(" ", "").
                       Substring(1)

            Case StringCase.Mixed_TitleLower

                output = String.Empty

                For X As Integer = 0 To Text.Length - 1 Step 2

                    Try
                        output &= Char.ToLower(Text(X)) &
                                  Char.ToUpper(Text(X + 1))

                    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
                        output &= Char.ToLower(Text(X))

                    End Try

                Next X

                Return output

            Case StringCase.Mixed_TitleUpper

                output = String.Empty

                For X As Integer = 0 To Text.Length - 1 Step 2

                    Try
                        output &= Char.ToUpper(Text(X)) &
                                  Char.ToLower(Text(X + 1))

                    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
                        output &= Char.ToUpper(Text(X))

                    End Try

                Next X

                Return output

            Case StringCase.Mixed_Word_Lower

                output = String.Empty

                For Each token As String In Text.Split
                    output &= StringRenamer.Rename(token, StringCase.Mixed_TitleLower) & " "
                Next token

                Return output

            Case StringCase.Mixed_Word_Upper

                output = String.Empty

                For Each token As String In Text.Split
                    output &= StringRenamer.Rename(token, StringCase.Mixed_TitleUpper) & " "
                Next token

                Return output

            Case StringCase.Toggle

                output = String.Empty

                For Each token As String In Text.Split
                    output &= Char.ToLower(token.First) & token.Substring(1).ToUpper & " "
                Next token

                Return output

            Case StringCase.Inverted

                output = String.Empty

                For Each c As Char In Text

                    output &= If(Char.IsLower(c),
                                 Char.ToUpper(c),
                                 Char.ToLower(c))

                Next c

                Return output

            Case Else

                Return Nothing

        End Select

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Rename a string to the specified StringCase,
    ''' Also find and replace text after rename.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function Rename(ByVal Text As String,
                                  ByVal sCase As StringCase,
                                  ByVal FindWhat As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex,
                                  ByVal ReplaceWith As String,
                                  ByVal RegExIgnoreCase As System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions) As String

        Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.
               Regex.Replace(StringRenamer.Rename(Text, sCase), FindWhat.ToString, ReplaceWith, RegExIgnoreCase)

    End Function

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: Text.First - Error 
What is this? What this Indicate ?

Comment: @Deep Indicates the first element of a sequence, in this case the first character of the text, is the same as doing this: `Text(0)`. If a method gives you an error then you should check if the passed string value is an empty string before calling the method.

Comment: @ ElektroStudios: Is those codes I have to type in the Class?
I have not tested this, I type on the same window as of my form...

Look on the error [image](http://s2.postimg.org/tpmze6761/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: @Deep `LINQ` extensions as `String.First` requires the usage of .NET Framework 3.5 (minimum), so you have two alternatives here, 1:Replace those `Text.First` to `Text(0)`, or 2:Target at least Framework 3.5 on your project.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is the long way.But,it works.Hope it helps.

```
    Dim strInput, m, n As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim i, i1 As Integer

   strInput = "converted. to title case"
    n = Len(strInput)
    For i1 = 1 To n
        Try
            m = strInput(i1 - 1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit For
        End Try
        If m = " " Then
            n = Len(strInput)
            strInput = Mid(strInput, i1 + 1, n)
            i = Len(strInput) - i1
            n = i1
            i1 = 0
            strTemp = strTemp & " "
        Else
            If i1 = 1 Then
                strTemp = strTemp & LCase(Mid(strInput, i1, 1))
            Else
                strTemp = strTemp & UCase(Mid(strInput, i1, 1))

            End If
        End If
    Next i1
    strOutput = strTemp 'for tOGGLE Case
Dim sentancecase As String = StrConv(title, VbStrConv.ProperCase)' For Sentence Case
```

Comment: Sorry to say,
But I can't understand the codes...
I mean where to type this ?
I am having the feature on menu bar and so what should I type on the "to Sentence case" and "to tOGGLE cASE"?
And where the rest code?

I am replacing the text so please so that information too.
or you can create a free project file and send me so that I can get it in details 
Thank you